# in OpenZeppelin's ERC721 why are tokenapprovals more restrictive that operatorApprovals

Tags: contract-design, erc-721, openzeppelin

In OpenZeppelin's ERC721 contract what was the design decision behind making `_tokenapprovals` a mapping, but `_operatorApprovals` a multidimensional mapping? Why restrict the ability to approve transfer of a single token, to only one address (`_tokenapprovals`), but create a data structure that gives multiple external addresses control over ALL account owned tokens (`_operatorApprovals`).  What where the practical scenarios envisaged to arrive at this pattern?

Answer (score 2):

This is a requirement of the ERC-721 standard.

- Token approvals are a one-per-token data model.
- Approvals-for-all are a one-per-operator-and

Answer (score 1):

`_tokenapprovals` is related to the function `approve` and`approve` is an approval specific to a tokenID

but

`_operatorApprovals` is related to the function `setApprovalForAll` and `setApprovalForAll` is for all tokenIds for a given ERC721 contract.